# Python - If row more than, do something

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and i'm trying to create a block of code that prints a statement if a value is more than a value I've defined. The below code however isn't working, it's not printing anything despite the values of row[4] being greater than '10'. Even when I try `== '55.9280':` it still doesn't satisfy the criteria, and itsn't printing anything. Thanks in advance!

The list is an output of a MySQL statement string convetred into a list. With row[4] being QueryTime.

```
Forename: Surname: Email: Querytime:
```

e.g.

```
for row in list:
    print row[4]
    if row[4] > '10':
        print("is greater than")
```

row 4 =

```
55.9280
45.5300
40.2040
38.7850
32.8320
32.5820
31.6290
30.0630
29.4950
28.9780
```

Comment: First consider working with numbers, not strings

Comment: what's the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `row` is a list of integers. Your mistake is that you are comparing an **integer** with a **string**. 
Correct code:

```
for row in list:
    print row[4]
    if row[4] > 10:
        print("is greater than")
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks mate! Will mark as correct when I can (6 mins)

Comment: @MichaelBlair glad to help :)

Comment: I'm curious, did your orignal code raise any errors, or did it just run without ever printing, "is greater than", row is a list of integers, then the line if row[4]>'10' should have caused an error, since you are comparing ints and strings?

Comment: @Tim It only throws error on Python 3, he must be coding in python 2.x, where there's no error caused

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print 55.9280 == '55.9280'
False
>>> print 55.9280 == 55.9280
True
>>> print 55.9280 > '10'
False
>>> print 55.9280 > 10
True
```

You need to pay attention to data types.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do (see [xyproblem.info](http://xyproblem.info)) but the following code is similar to yours and doesn't crash. You need to convert between strings and integers if that is what you want.

```
[list = \[\[1,2,3,4,5\], \[5,10,15,20,25\], \[15,16,17,18,19\], \[20,21,22,23,24\], \[21,22,23,24,25\]\]

for row in list:
    print row\[4\]
    if row\[4\] > int('10'):
        print("is greater than")][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are dealing with strings and not numbers. Even if a string consists of numerical digits it is still considered like a word as far as python is concerned, and it just doesn't make any sense to ask if one word is 'greater than' another word.

It wouldn't make sense to ask is 'hello world'>17 and it would make no more sense to ask if '18'>17. You should think of '18' like a word.

Infact, if you try and compare a string and an integer, python should raise an error. Something like this:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

The fact that your program isn't raising any errors would suggest you are comparing strings with strings (which again doesn't make very much sense) and so you need to convert your stings into numbers. I would suggest the following:

```
if float(row[4]) > 10:
```

You are now comparing two numbers, which makes sense.

I would use float instead of int, since looking at your data, your numbers are not whole numbers.